# Debug Qt application among dlls

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

I have Qt project with multiple children projects, most of them are dll's. And exactly one is Qt application.
How to launch debugging of application? Can it be done in some config file to allow other users of versioning system to use same settings all over the team.

Of course I know the way to "attach" to already existing process. But starting from environment is more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt Creator click Build > Run configuration and check the project that you want to run. Pressing F5 will start the debugger.
The setting should be saved in your project.pro.user file.